Approximate square root of Dirac delta function on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\AdS{AdS}$I hope to find a sequence of complex-valued functions $\{f_i(g)\}$ on the group element $g$ of a locally compact group $\SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ so that the cross-correlation
$F_i(g_1) \equiv \int f_i^*(g)f_i(g \cdot g_1) dg$ approaches a constant function 1 pointwise. The group multiplication is $\cdot$, $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$, and $dg$ is the Haar measure. That is, find $\{f_i: \SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}\}$ such that
$$\int f_i^*(g)f_i(g \cdot g_1) dg \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} 1 \text{ pointwise} .$$
Some related questions are:
Real line case but our question is less restrictive since we just need pointwise convergence here. If we change our group to translations on the real line $\mathbb{R}$, then Gaussian functions with increasing width can be the $\{f_i\}$.
Why do we want unitary representations of locally compact groups into $B(H)$? is some general knowledge that may be useful for our question. For reference, the group $\SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not amenable.
Some other maybe helpful references on convolutions of functions on groups Approximations of the identity on Lie groups and homogenous spaces, The convolution of a $L^1$ function and an approximate identity. The wanted $\{f_i\}$ looks like approximate identities but still not quite. Also another maybe useful fact, the group manifold $\SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the pseudo-Riemannian manifold anti de Sitter 3 spacetime $\AdS_3$.
(I am a physicist trying to solve a physics question so please ask for clarifications if I used some inappropriate math terms.)

It may potentially be that there is no such a function.

If someone can find a complete construction, please leave your contact information for credits. Partial answers are also very welcome

If I have interpreted your formulas correctly, I think that such nets can be constructed when showing that the group SL(2,R) is weakly amenable. I will try to look up the precise details later this week if no one else is able to confirm/contradict this claim.

Just to check, what you have written is the complex cross-correlation. Do you actually want that, or do you want $f_i(g^{-1} g_1)$ to make it a convolution?

@KevinCasto, I think the $*$ means $g \mapsto \overline{f_i(g^{-1})}$.

@KevinCasto Thanks for the comments. I think it should be the cross-correlation and I edited my question accordingly (it actually comes from a norm squared). There is no tag called "cross-correlation" so maybe I should keep the "convolution" tag. I am also not sure how much difference these two concepts make for this question.

@LSpice If it is supposed to be convolution, it shouldn't have the complex conjugation. And if the question (as in the linked one) is supposed to be Fourier-dual to asking for the square root of the Dirac delta, then I guess it should be convolution and not cross-correlation.

@KevinCasto If the current question title is not appropriate, any help on editing is very appreciated!

I understand from the comments that when you write $f_i^*(g)$ you mean $\overline{f_i(g)}$ (the complex conjugate of the complex number $f_i(g)$), so that if $\rho(g_1)$ is the representation by right-multiplication on $L_2(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$, $$\mathrm{Re}(\int f_i^*(g)f_i(g \cdot g_1) dg) =  \|f_i\|_2^2 - \frac 1 2 \|f_i - \rho(g_1) f_i\|_2^2$$
and you are asking for a sequence $f_i$ in $L_2(G)$ such that $\lim_i \|f_i\|_2^2=1$ (so we can as well assume $\|f_i\|_2=1$) and $\lim_i \|f_i - \rho(g_1)f_i\|_2=0$ pointwise. If you mean $\overline{f_i(g^{-1})}$ of $f_i(g^{-1})$ as in the question you refer to, then this becomes a completely different question.
If my interpretation is correct, then the answer is that there does not exist such a sequence. The point is that, for a general locally compact group, asking for the existence of a net $f_i$ with pointwise convergence (resp. uniform convergence on compact sets) are both equivalent to the amenability of $G$. This is what is called Dixmier's property in wikipedia. I am not aware of an obvious proof of the interesting implication "pointwise for a net implies uniform on compacta for another net". The one that I have in mind uses Hahn-Banach through Mazur's lemma. For a proof of the full equivalences, see Proposition 8.8 in Pier's book Amenable locally compact groups where the equivalences are explicitely stated. It is perhaps easier to get the idea by reading Theorem G.3.1 in Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette's book Kazhdan's property (T) where the result is concisely shown for $L_1$ instead of $L_2$, and Remark G.3.3 there.
In particular, your condition implies the amenability of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$, which, as you recall, is well-known to be false.
Note however that if you are happy to define amenability in terms of the existence of an invariant mean on $L_\infty(G)$, then the fact that your condition implies the amenability of $G$ is easy : if $f_i$ was a net in $L_2(G)$ with pointwise convergence $\int f_i^*(g)f_i(g \cdot g_1) dg \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} 1$, then any weak-* accumulation point of $|f_i|^2$ in the dual of $L_\infty(G)$ would be an invariant mean.

I didn't see where the original question required the net $(f_i)$ to satisfy any boundedness conditions - did I overlook something? This is why I thought weak amenability of ${\rm SL}_2({\bf R})$ might be relevant.

@YemonChoi Well, for $g_1$ the identity, (with my interpretation) you get $|f_i|_2^2 \to 1$, so we can as well assume that $|f_i|_2=1$. But in the other interpretation nothing guarantees the boundedness of $(f_i)$, that is the reason why things become so different. I am even tempted to believe that the condition holds for any locally compact group. It holds whenever the center of $G$ is not compact.

As a slight extension, I hope to double check with you that SO(1,n) the indefinite orthogonal groups are also not amenable as they contain SO(1,2) as the subgroup (related to this question since SL(2,R) is a double cover of SO(1,2)). Hence such nets f_i do not exist for any SO(1,n) group.

@XYSquared , in general any (non compact) semi simple Lie group is easily seen to be non-amenable (consider the action on $G/P$ and its lack of invariant measures)...

@MikaeldelaSalle Sorry I think there is some typo in your line of aligned equation, or the claim that ||f - rho f|| = 0

SO(1,1) seems to be the only SO(1,n) that is amenable. And its amenability is because SO(1,1) is abelian. And if I understand correctly, you are saying my conditions are fully equivalent to amenability. Hence such a sequence exists for SO(1,1).

@XYSquared Sorry, I fixed the typo. And you are right for everything: such a sequence exists for $\mathrm{SO}(n,1)$ if and only if it is amenable (true for any locally compact $\sigma$-compact group), if and only if $n=1$.
